# Function template or Gereric function is the right term?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Im kind of stuck on this. I read in a book that we can make Generic functions with function template but on other places, author called the generic function, an function template. witch is proper for example:

```
template <class T> void printSmt(T x){}
```

in here `printSmt` is called generic function or function template?

And another question: is `x` in parameter list of function `printSmt` a generic type or  a template parameter?

EDIT: im writing some documents for my school. if it's possible give me an answer according to C++ reference.

Comment: There's no such term as "generic function" in the C++ standard. The word "generic" pertains more to the *style* of programming that usually involves templates in C++.

Comment: And since function templates aren't functions, I'd be very reluctant to call a function template a "generic function". It's not a function. (By contrast, a template function is a function.) In mathematics there's sometimes a weird inversion of qualification (more qualified is less specific), but that's bad hygiene that we don't need to drag into programming.

Comment: `x` is the function's formal parameter, just like in non-template functions. Its type is `T`, the template parameter. There are no "generic types" in C++ that I've heard of. (BTW: When you say "I read in a book" it's considered good practice to include the title and author of said book.)

Comment: `s/Template function/Function template/`. It is a template for generating functions, not a function that is a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ Standard calls it function template. The term generic function is more used in other object-oriented languages (e.g. in LISP these are functions with the same name). Java uses generic types to implement a minimal approach of generic programming.

`x` is the function parameter. `T` is the template parameter. In `printSmt<int>()` `int` is the template argument.